# Would this usage of the word ''industrial'' be appropriate?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, terminology

For context, I am writing about an industrial reputation, which is in reference to a reputation one has when in the industry (i.e Hollywood or the 'music industry'). Would it be correct to use industrial, then, as a way of referencing the music industry or film industry, or would I need to use a different word?

If so, which would be appropriate?

Comment: Can you give specific examples of how you want to use it in a sentence?

Comment: Seems wrong to me.  His reputation within the music industry would not be called his "industrial reputation".

Comment: No. You can have a reputation ***in the** [music, movie, whatever] **industry***, but idiomatically speaking there's no such thing as an ***industrial*** reputation. But sometimes ***industrial*** may be used to mean ***industry-strength*** (very strong, as might be appropriate to industrial applications). So someone *might* come up with the semi-facetious nonce usage *He has an industrial [-strength] reputation*. Similar to "Teflon Tony" (Blair), whose reputation seemed for a long time to be impervious to criticism following bad political / military decisions he made as UK Prime Minister.

Comment: Perhaps “rude mechanicals” would fit the entertainment industry.

Comment: Using *industrial experience* would cause too much confusion with its sense of  *manufacturing*. Instead, just use *music industry experience* or *film industry experience*. (I would have provided this as an actual answer, but it turns out that making this a good objective answer is beyond my ability. The dictionary definitions of the words don't support my advice, even though I know that the use of *industrial* in this sense is unidiomatic.)